# Projection of Rectangle from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, computer-vision

Lets have two known vectors $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ in XY ($\mathbb{R}^2$) representing the orthogonal projection of two unknown vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with known lengths $|x_1|=l_1$, $|x_1|=l_2$, and $x_1\cdot x_2=0$.

Let be the orthogonal projection made through $\hat z$, thus projecting orthogonally onto XY.

Consider the simple case of $x_1$ lying on X, i.e. $x_1'=l_1 \hat x$.

Trivially in this case:
$$x_1=(l_1,0,0)\\
x_2=(0,|x_2'|,\sin \arccos \frac{|x_2'|}{l_2})
$$

**How should i calculate the $x_1$ and $x_2$ vectors in the general case**, for any given $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ image vectors, any in the sense they were indeed projected from a rectangle with sides $l_1$ and $l_2$?.

Comment: Your title says “perspective projection,” but in the body of the question you only talk about orthogonal projections.

Comment: Corrected......

Comment: OK, so are you basically asking about a rectangle in general position being projected orthogonally onto the $x$-$y$ plane?

Comment: Yes that is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I’m going to use slightly different notation from yours so as not to confuse coordinates with vectors.)

For each of the vectors $\mathbf v_1'=(x_1,y_1,0)$ and $\mathbf v_2'=(x_2,y_2,0)$ there are two possible pre-images, even in your simple example: $\mathbf v_1=\left(x_1,y_1,\pm\sqrt{l_1^2-x_1^2-y_1^2}\right)$ and $\mathbf v_2=\left(x_2,y_2,\pm\sqrt{l_2^2-x_2^2-y_2^2}\right)$, respectively. This is a simple application of the Pythagorean theorem. That gives you four possibilities for the original rectangle. The additional constraint $$\begin{align} \mathbf v_1\cdot\mathbf v_2 &= x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2 \\ &= x_1x_2+y_1y_2\pm\sqrt{l_1^2-x_1^2-y_1^2}\sqrt{l_2^2-x_2^2-y_2^2} \\ &= \mathbf v_1'\cdot\mathbf v_2'\pm\sqrt{l_1^2-\|\mathbf v_1'\|^2}\sqrt{l_2^2-\|\mathbf v_2'\|^2} \\ &=0 \end{align}$$ will allow you to eliminate some of these combinations, but in general you’ll end up with two possibilities for the original rectangle. If the angle between $\mathbf v_1'$ and $\mathbf v_2'$ is acute, then the signs of $z_1$ and $z_2$ must be different, but they can be either $+/-$ or $-/+$. Similarly, if the angle is obtuse, then the signs of the two $z$-coordinates are the same, but there’s no way to decide with the information at hand whether they should be positive or negative. (If $\mathbf v_1'\cdot\mathbf v_2'=0$, then the rectangle is parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane.)

Comment: I got it.... it was simple afterwards. Maybe i was trying to get a closed solution?... This is perfectly fine.

Comment: Incidentally, this sign ambiguity underlies [a classic optical illusion](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/i-cubi-modellano-vettore-11159796.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* an answer to your question, but rather just pointing
out (tangentially), as reflected in 
[this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/210588/6094),
that projecting a $90^\circ$ rectangle angle
can result in a much smaller planar angle:

---

[image: ProjectionCex]

          

<sup>An angle is $68^\circ$ incident to $v$ in 3D,
but it projects to $45^\circ$ in 2D.</sup>

---

Comment: Sure the angle will change, not neccesarily smaller, and discarding of course the degenerate cases of reducing them to zero, i still dont see a solution to this projection problem...

Comment: Where did you make that drawing?

Comment: @hyprfrcb: I am sorry that I am not solving your projection problem.

Comment: Also a 90 certex can map into a bigger angle. But i don see your point then....

Comment: @hyprfrcb: Only that it is not straightforward.